# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. on CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I just transfer my domain and migration my hosting server to the order service hosting but the transfer domain are still pending process. I got a new username and password for my cpanel and my web site showing error like this :

```
    A Database Error Occurred

    Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

    Filename: core/Loader.php

    Line Number: 346
```

I am using CodeIgniter 3 and MySQL for this web and I think that the problem in the config directory on the `database.php` file . I was change the old username `password` and `username` in `database.php`. But the result is still not change.

This Is my database.php :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '(*My IP Domain)';
$db['default']['username'] = '(*My Username Cpanel)';
$db['default']['password'] = '(*My Password Cpanel)';
$db['default']['database'] = '(*My Database name)';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I don't know how to fix it, whether the error may in another file ?

Comment: use `mysqli` instead `mysql`

Comment: @Sofyan Thayf it's Still Error

Answer (score 0):

If you're **using shared hosting**, you should have to **define DB name with your domain prefix**.

Ex: If my site is `stackoverflow` then I might able to create `stackoverflow_tabalename`

So your table name will be `stackoverflow_tabalename` and DB User is also should act the same approach (`stackoverflow_userName`)

and use MySQLi, Cz 3.0 stop supporting MySQL

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'stackoverflow_tabalename';
$db['default']['password'] = 'stackoverflow_userName';
$db['default']['database'] = 'passwordGoesHere';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

> **Note:** Use [**`MySQL® Database Wizard`**](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-set-up-a-database-using-the-mysql-database-wizard-in-cpanel/) to create database, User and password.

Answer (score 0):

```
$active_group = 'default';

$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(

'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'your-user-name',
'password' => 'your-password',
'database' => 'DB-name',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Answer (score 0):

on database.php
change mysql to mysqli

if still error

change php version same as you use on local

Comment: Can you explain further? Why does this help?

Comment: for change mysql to mysqli , because its deprecated, not recommend use that. For php version some function maybe un-useable because php version or hosting disabled some ext.

Comment: so change the version of php can solved my problem, in my case using 000webhostapp (latest php 7.1), with wampp (php 5) as localhost